# Что быстрее проверить - "больше нуля" либо "не равняется нулю"?

Tags: java, производительность, сравнение

Что лучше использовать?

```
a > 0
```

или

```
a != 0
```

В обоих случаях представим, что нас не интересует ничего кроме того, что число должно быть больше нуля.

Имеется ввиду в плане производительности, что сделать легче - проверить на больше или не равно ?

Comment: при прочих равных, пишите так, чтобы код был максимально понятен и прост.

Comment: Если _число должно быть больше нуля_ - пишем `a > 0`, если _число не равно нулю_ - `a != 0` Кажется, всё логично

Comment: Я имею ввиду в плане производительности, что сделать легче проверить на больше или не равно ?

Comment: это очень спорный момент. Если оптимизатор нормальный - он сократит "лишнюю" операцию. Но с точки зрения обьектов, если а это вычисляемое поле, и при двух вызвах оно должно увеличивать счётчик - то оптимизация не произойдёт и будет два сравнения, что ухудшит производительность.

Comment: Два сравнения с точки зрения виртуальной машины - тяжелее чем одно.

Comment: В одном случае используется инструкция `ifeq` (jump if zero), в другом - `ifle` (jump if less than or equal to zero), так что производительность должна быть сопоставима.  Скорее всего для процессоров также используются по одной инструкции на каждый из типов сравнения.

Comment: Надо смотреть в генерируемый код java машины, но по факту разницы вообще не должно быть т.к. выполняется ассемблерная команда cmp и дальше нужная команда прыжка проверяющая один регистр. Думаю на JVM это ляжет аналогичным способом.

Comment: `test eax, eax; js negative`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

рассмотрим тестовый класс

```
public class OpsTest
{
    public boolean gZero(int a)
    {
        return a > 0;
    }

    public boolean neZero(int a)
    {
        return a != 0;
    }
}
```

в байт коде видим следующее:

```
  // Method descriptor #15 (I)Z
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 2
  public boolean gZero(int a);
    0  iload_1 [a]
    1  ifle 6
    4  iconst_1
    5  ireturn
    6  iconst_0
    7  ireturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 15]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 8] local: this index: 0 type: OpsTest
        [pc: 0, pc: 8] local: a index: 1 type: int
      Stack map table: number of frames 1
        [pc: 6, same]

  // Method descriptor #15 (I)Z
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 2
  public boolean neZero(int a);
    0  iload_1 [a]
    1  ifeq 6
    4  iconst_1
    5  ireturn
    6  iconst_0
    7  ireturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 20]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 8] local: this index: 0 type: OpsTest
        [pc: 0, pc: 8] local: a index: 1 type: int
      Stack map table: number of frames 1
        [pc: 6, same]
```

видим, что разница заключается в операторах ifle и ifeq, т.о., как уже говорили в комментариях, (ощутимой) разницы в производительности не будет, пишите код так что бы было читабельно.